# Verificar datos pendientes por indexar ELASTICSEARCH

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, kibana

Estoy enviando los datos para los INDICES DE ELASTICSEARCH y en mi logstash configuro el .conf el cual le indico un query de SQL y todo parece ser correcto
luego voy a KIBANA (previamente abro el tunel ssh de elasticsearch) en el devtool para verificar el proceso de indexado de datos.

CONSULTA SQL

```
SELECT V1.product_id, category_id, category_name, fullname, image, relevance, color, title, brand, vitrina, price, model, weight, height, is_prime, sales_quantity,bestseller , rating FROM (SELECT random() , p.product_id, p.category_id,c.name as category_name,c.fullname,f.url as image,p.relevance, p.color, p.title,p.brand, CASE WHEN p.vitrina IS TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS vitrina,p.price, p.model, p.weight, p.height, p.is_prime,0 AS sales_quantity,CASE WHEN p.bestseller IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE p.bestseller END AS bestseller,CASE WHEN p.rating IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE rating END AS rating FROM products p JOIN categories c on p.category_id = c.category_id JOIN files f on p.product_id = f.product_id WHERE f.main = 1 AND p.status = 1 AND package_weight <= 120 order by p.relevance asc) V1
```

IMAGEN DEL DEVTOOL
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
lo que esta señalado en rojo son los documentos pendientes por indexar, pero nunca terminan y no se donde ver cual es la razon.

MAPPING DEL INDICE

```
PUT productos_v0_busqueda
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding",
                    "snowball"
                ]   
            }
        } 
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
    "@timestamp" : {
      "type" : "date"
    },
    "@version" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
    "bestseller" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
    "category_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
    "category_name" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "fullname" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "height" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "image" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "is_prime" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
    "model" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "product_id" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
    "rating" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
    "relevance" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
    "store_id" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
    "vitrina" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
    "weight" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "sales_quantity": {
        "type": "double"
      },
    "price": {
        "type": "double"
      },
    "brand": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
    "color": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
    "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },      
    "title_ots": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          },
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
    "cat_level_0": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "all_categories",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        } 
      },
    "cat_level_1": {
        "type": "text",
            "copy_to": "all_categories",
         "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        } 
      },
    "cat_level_2": {
        "type": "text",
            "copy_to": "all_categories",
         "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        } 
      },
    "cat_level_3": {
        "type": "text",
            "copy_to": "all_categories",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }  
      },
    "cat_level_4": {
        "type": "text",
            "copy_to": "all_categories",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }          
      },
    "cat_level_5": {
        "type": "text",
            "copy_to": "all_categories",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }          
      },    
    "all_categories": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
      },
    "status":{
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "discount_percentage":{
        "type" : "float"
      },
      "stock":{
        "type" : "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sin embargo este parece que no esta indexando todos los datos y deja unos cuantos en pendiente.
¿saben  de que manera puedo ver porque quedaron pendientes? ya que en el log no me muestra ningun error ni nada similar que me permita identificar cual es la falla.

Comment: Probaste revisar los logs de Logstash? No los de Elasticsearch, los de Logstash. Si un dato no matchea con el mapping por ejemplo, lo vas a ver en Logstash.

Comment: @Emeeus que pena no haber respondido antes, si ya logre identificar la falla el problema era debido a que el servidor estaba colapsando en recursos entonces no era capaz de hacer el proceso completo